# Как получить запрос с пробелами в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Отправляю данные на сервер:

```
'   test_data   '
```

В `Request $request` приходят:

```
'test_data   '
```

Как получить данные с пробелами (не тримить их)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо добавить наше поле в защищённое свойство класса `TrimStrings`:

```php
class TrimStrings extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
        'my_other_input' // Наше поле
    ];

// [...]
```

*Полный ответ дан [Ilgala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2343305/ilgala)*